# How to Solve this definite integral: $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int\limits^\infty_t \frac{1}{x^2+1} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have a problem to evaluate this definite integral.

Evaluate the definite integral:

$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{t} \frac{1}{x^2+1} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$$

Comment: There is no nice closed form.

Comment: But obviously the integral is less than $$\frac{1}{t^2+1}\,\text{Erfc}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

Comment: Can you give me the answer about the integral less than $\frac{1}{t^2+1} Erfc (\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}})$?

Comment: It is an obvious inequality: over the integration range, $\frac{1}{x^2+1}\leq\frac{1}{t^2+1}$.

Comment: @VivianZhang please, share with us your attempt, because (1) it's better for you to learn better, and (2) we can understand where you're stuck, so that we can give you better advices.

Comment: A closed form was possible.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio *There is no nice closed form.* - How did you arrive at this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I(z)=\int_t^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2x^2}}{1+x^2}$$
We wanna find $I\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$
$\DeclareMathOperator\erfc{erfc}$
$$I'(z)=\int_t^\infty\frac{-2zx^2ze^{-z^2x^2}}{1+x^2}$$
$$I'(z)=-2z\int_t^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2x^2}(1+x^2-1)}{1+x^2}$$
$$I'(z)=-2z\int_t^\infty{e^{-z^2x^2}}dx+2z\int_t^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2x^2}}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$I'(z)=-2z\int_t^\infty{e^{-z^2x^2}}dx+2z\int_t^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2x^2}}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$I'(z)=-2z\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\erfc(zt)}{2z}+2zI(z)$$
$$I'(z)=-\sqrt{\pi}\erfc(zt)+2zI(z)$$

Given $I(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(t)$

$$I(z)=\left\{\left\{\frac{e^{z^2}\left(4\pi t T\left(\sqrt{2} tz,\frac{1}{t}\right)-\pi t\text{erf}(z)+\pi t \text{erf}(z)\text{erf}(tz)+\pi t-2t\tan^{-1}(t)-2t\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)}{2t}\right\}\right\}$$

We needed to find $I\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$

$$I(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\left\{\left\{\frac{\sqrt{e} \left(4\pi  T\left( t,\frac{1}{t}\right)-\pi \text{erf}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+\pi  \text{erf}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\text{erf}(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}})+\pi -2\tan^{-1}(t)-2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)}{2}\right\}\right\}$$
Where $$T(x,a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^a\frac{e^{-x^2 \frac{1+t^2}{2}}}{1+t^2}dt$$

dont forget to multiply by $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ at the end ;)
$$I=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left\{\left\{\frac{\sqrt{e} \left(4\pi  T\left( t,\frac{1}{t}\right)-\pi \text{erf}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+\pi  \text{erf}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\text{erf}(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}})+\pi -2\tan^{-1}(t)-2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)}{2}\right\}\right\}$$
Oh ya I tested it for t=0 and I got
$$\sqrt{\frac{e\pi}{2}}\erfc{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$
which is equal to
$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: I used wolfram for finding I(z), im sure there is a human way to find the answer though

Comment: Needs explicit definition of $T$

Comment: T is the Owen T function, I will add that